# Divide data file as unique data each iteration among multiple virtual users in Gatling

Tags: gatling, scala-gatling

I'm Interest on how we can divide test data unique among multiple threads in Gatling

Example
Virtual users : 3
Data in file : 9

Divide 3 data into each virtual user

user 1 : dataline 1, dataline 2 ,dataline 3
user 2 : dataline 4, dataline 5,dataline 6
user 3 : dataline 7, dataline 8, dataline 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This guide is not only yet (it will only be along with the Gatling 3.7 release), but you can check the [doc sources commit](https://github.com/gatling/gatling/commit/342d3beffb22aa16a23afb6fb33cfadc6e7c58e3) for an example on how to do this kind of things.

Basically, you have to use `readRecords` to grab all the data from your csv file, and then apply whatever grouping strategy you want.